# java string regex head not contains

Tags: regex, linux

I have a string :

```
[root@slave1 ~]# test -d /root/workspace/Servers || echo not found
[root@slave1 ~]# test -d /root/workspace/Servers || echo not found
not found
[root@slave1 ~]# test -d /root/workspace/Servers || echo not found
[root@slave1 ~]# test -d Desktp || echo not found
not found
```

And I want to find the word `not found`  without `echo`  at first

As you can see , in this string , there will 2 match

How can I do ??

Comment: How is this java related?

Comment: It's terminal message in linux, I want to check if it echo ````not found```  ,return false

Comment: @user2492364 but why is this tagged as java question?!

Comment: Removed java tag and added linux, please retag if not appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind.

```
"(?<!\\becho )not found(?=\\s|$)"
```

You could use the same regex in grep.

```
grep -oP '(?<!\becho )not found(?=\s|$)' file
```

`(?<!\becho )` -  Don't lookafter to `echo<space>`

`not found(?=\s|$)` -  But match all the `not found` strings which must be followed by a space or line end.

Comment: could you explain the regex for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` with start anchor:

```
grep '^not found' file
not found
not found
```